# Dynamically select fields from a list and add them to a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In a form I need to dynamically add (and then remove) some fields (0 to n) from a select.

Every item should be removed from the list after being added so it can't be selected twice.

For example I have a select like this:

```
 <select name="list">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
  </select>
```

And I want to add a new field in my form that shows A and D and stores their values so I can get it through a POST. Then if I click on the select, there will be just B and C.

Can you help me?

Comment: did you try something

Comment: Please elaborate. What I understood is, user will select from the main list and as and when he/she selects you want a new list to be created which will keep on adding the selected items. At the same time, you want them to be removed from the main list. Am I right?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to select multiple values, just use checkboxes. Four checkboxes, A, B, C, and D will provide you with exactly the functionality you want, without even needing JavaScript, and without introducing some awkward UI.

Comment: Iterate with forloop using    $('body').find(":selected")[0].length && $('body').find(":selected")[0].value and add value to some array variable

Comment: Checkboxes are not good for what I need. The list can be pretty long.

Comment: Chinamy Baid you got the point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type of fields do you want? Input type text? If so:

```
$("[name=list]").on("change", function (e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val.length > 0) {
        $(this).find("option:selected").remove();
        $("<input>").attr("name", "the-name").val(val).appendTo($("#the-form"))
    }
});
```

check out the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/etoysp7b/1/

Comment: I need just text and store the value in a hidden variable. How can I delete A for example? (and then add it again to my select list) and retrieve the values in a POST?

Comment: maintain an array and keep adding the selected values to that. Use the values of this array in your POST call. Use a text area to show the values of this array.

Comment: Or keep hidden fields and some kind of remove button. updated fiddel https://jsfiddle.net/etoysp7b/8/

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are looking for this,

```
$("select[name='list']").on('change',function(){
   var b=$(this).val();
    if(b!=0){
    $("#s1").append("<input type='text' name='newname"+b+"' value='"+$(this).find("option:selected").text()+"'/>");
    $(this).find("option[value='"+b+"']").remove();
    }
});
```

AND

```
<form id="s1">
<select name="list">
     <option value="0">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
  </select>


</form>
```

Comment: I need to store the value of every selected option in a hidden variable. How can I delete A for example? (and then add it again to my select list) and retrieve the values in a POST?

Comment: @Ame You dont want to remove the elements from select?then just comment this line ` $(this).find("option[value='"+b+"']").remove()`. But that will allow duplicate values,to avoid that you could disable option tags once selected

Comment: No, I want to restore an option if I was wrong. For instance, if I click on A and then I realize I was wrong, how can I get back? I need a way to restore it :)

Comment: @Ame OK but how do you want to check if user input was wrong or right?

Comment: it's his problem :) I would add just a delete option, an X for instance, for restoring the previous situation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these options as well : 1. http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/  2. https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistbox/index.htm#demos/jqxlistbox/dragdrop.htm